# How to obtain the derivative of the wave function of a harmonic oscillator using ladder operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, harmonic-oscillator

> I want to show that by applying the ladder operators one can obtain:
> $$
> \Psi^{'}(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}x_0}(\sqrt{n}\Psi_{n-1}(x) - \sqrt{n+1}\Psi_{n+1}(x))  
> $$
> with:
> $\Psi_n(x) = C e^{-\frac{\xi^2}{2}} H_n(\xi)$, $\space C = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n! 2^n \sqrt{\pi}x_0}}$ , $\space \xi = \frac{x}{x_0}$ and $\space x_0^2 = \frac{\hbar}{m\omega}$

My approach: 
I know following properties for the ladder operators:
$\space a |n \rangle = \sqrt{n} |n-1 \rangle\space $ and $\space a^\dagger |n \rangle = \sqrt{n+1}|n+1\rangle$ 
I can see that the equation can be rewritten as:
$$
|\Psi^{'}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}x_0}(a|\Psi_n \rangle - a^\dagger |\Psi_n\rangle)
$$
By using the properties mentioned above we obtain:
$$
|\Psi^{'}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}x_0}(\sqrt{n}|\Psi_{n-1} \rangle - \sqrt{n+1}|\Psi_{n+1} \rangle)
$$
However, I am not sure why that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what the question is here. The last and first equations you wrote are virtually the same, maybe you're confused because the notation is not the best. In the last equation you should write $\vert \Psi' \rangle$ for the right-hand side of the equation is a combination of states. Remember that when you use the bra-ket notation you are not bounding the expression to any basis, therefore we normally write $\Psi (x)=\langle x \vert \Psi \rangle$. In that fashion, you can do $\langle x \vert \Psi' \rangle$ in the last equation and verify you get the first one. If I haven't answered your question please comment.

Comment: Maybe to clarify: I am starting with the esxpression $\Psi (x)$ and want to find the derivative by using ladder operators. I am having a hard time to undertand how to use the ladder operators in order to obtain the derivative.

Comment: I guess the best way to do that is to derivate directly in the expression of $\Psi(x) $, maybe use some Hermite polynomials properties and you will get something you can identify as the $n±1$ terms. Also remember that $\Psi(x) =\Psi_n (x) $

Answer (score 2):

If you express the ladder operators in the position basis you’ll get what to do. Use the following fact:
$$\mathscr{O}|\psi\rangle=\int \mathscr{O}|x\rangle\langle x|\psi\rangle dx$$

Remember that the ladder operators are linear combinations of position and momentum operators.